# How to check if element with class is first-child of that class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to directly check an element, if it is the first element from the parent with the given class?

i know i could get the parent -> get children with the given class and check if the first child is equal with the element, but this seems not the right way i think.. isnt there a "better" solution?

```js
// is obviously not first-child
console.log($('#check').is(':first-child'));       // false
console.log($('#check').is('.child:first-child')); // false
console.log($('#check').is('.child:first'));       // false

// want to get true for "element is first child with this class"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="parent">
    <div class="something"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="something"></div>
 <div class="child" id="check"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are looking for a single selector to that, I don't think there is one

Comment: `var $check = $('#check');
console.log($check .is($check.parent().children('.child:first'))); // false`

Comment: Try `$('#check').index()`. `0` would be first position.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, that gave me `true` (`$check .is($check.parent().children('.child:first'))`)

Comment: "i know i could get the parent -> get children with the given class and check if the first child is equal with the element, but this seems not the right way i think" Why not?

Comment: @BoltClock thought more about a possible speedissue (couse i use this in an dragover event and have check this very often - but this is anoter story) and.. it looks ugly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option you can try is to check whether `#check` is present in the set of first `.child` elements of `.parent`s

```
$('.parent').find('.child:first').is('#check');
```

Here we finds all the first `.child` descendant of `.parent` then checks whether `#checks` is one of them

Another is to check whether `#check` is the first `.child` child of `#check`s parent like

```
var $check = $('#check');
$check.is($check.parent().children('.child:first'))
```

So

```js
// is obviously not first-child
snippet.log($('#check').is(':first-child')); // false
snippet.log($('#check').is('.child:first-child')); // false
snippet.log($('#check').is('.child:first')); // false



var $check = $('#check');
snippet.log($check.is($check.parent().children('.child:first')));

snippet.log($('.parent').find('.child:first').is('#check')); // false
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="child" id="check"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i didnt know that `is()` is also to check equal elements. your shorthand for parent->child->first seems for me the best possible solution right now, thank you

Comment: So what are you asking the OP to try here? Please add an *explanation* to your code; this is next to useless because I have to carefully parse your sample line by line and compare it to the question to see what changed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

**Edit**: `for each` loop added.

```js
$(".parent").each(function(index) {
  alert($(this).find(".child").first().is($("#check")))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="child" id="check"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No because if you then have multiple such parent elements, and #check is not in the first such parent, then the check will fail.

Comment: Oh I just was about to reply, but you understand it :)

Comment: in my case i have to start checking by the element `#check`, which is why i cant use this snipped - but its correct, and works. thank you!